# How to get results for web scraping for different cells with a different url?

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am setting up a spreadsheet that will get the NAV for specific index funds every day from the blackrock website. There are a number of these index funds however and the URL changes for each cell. I am unsure how to make my way down the spreadsheet table I have made and place the target value in another cell.

I have tried listing every possible URL one after another and it seems to work, however, I keep receiving a run-time error so I must assume there is a more efficient way of doing this.

```
Sub GetCurrentPrices()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim text As String

    With CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
        .navigate "https://www.blackrock.com/uk/individual/products/xxxxxx/"
        Do While .Busy And .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        text = .document.getElementsByClassName("header-nav-data")(0).innerText
        .Quit
    End With

    ws.Cells(32, 1).Value = text

    With CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
        .navigate "https://www.blackrock.com/uk/individual/products/yyyyyy/"
        Do While .Busy And .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        text = .document.getElementsByClassName("header-nav-data")(0).innerText
        .Quit
    End With

    ws.Cells(33, 1).Value = text

End Sub
```

Currently, this code is copied about 22 times for each different URL. I have also tried something like this:

```
Sub GetCurrentPrices2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim text As String
    Dim i As Integer
    i=32

    With CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
        .navigate "https://www.blackrock.com/uk/individual/products/" & (ws.Range("H2:H24").Value) & "/"
        Do While .Busy And .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        text = .document.getElementsByClassName("header-nav-data")(0).innerText
        .Quit
    End With

    Do Until i > 46
        ws.Cells(i,1).Value = text
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that Column A contains the index fund of interest, and that the data starts at Row 2, your code can be re-written as follows...

```
Sub GetCurrentPrices()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim text As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        For i = 2 To lastRow
            .navigate "https://www.blackrock.com/uk/individual/products/" & ws.Cells(i, 1).Value & "/"
            Do While .Busy And .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
            text = .document.getElementsByClassName("header-nav-data")(0).innerText
            ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = text
        Next i
        .Quit
    End With

    Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```